# What does index stand for near the vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

We have a vector:

$\mathbf{v}^{(0)} = (0, 0, ..., 1, ..., 0, 0)$

I can't understand what *u* stand for to the right of vector:

$\ (\mathbf{v}^{(0)})_u = \{$ 1 when u = s, 0 when u ≠ s

u is not defined in document, so I ask there

s stands for node in graph, (0) stands for timestep in breadth-first search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscript enumerates the vector's components.

Comment: I think you mean it determines the components

Comment: @J.W.Tanner How is that verb choice better?

Comment: I thought enumerate means to count, but I see it can also mean to [specify](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/enumerate?s=t), which may be what you intended